# based on the status column using ifelse how to display diff background colors in td

Tags: php, html

in the while loop data based on the statusid value how to display different background colors

**Code show here**

```
 echo "<tr> 
       <td>".$result['exportid']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['deb_nmr']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['cost_name']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['numb_pal']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['tot_weight']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['pb_s']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['date']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['statusid']."</td>
 </tr>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch inside looping and before echo statement to get color as below:

```
$color = "";
switch ($result['statusid']) {
    case "1":
        $color = "#ddd";
        break;
    case "2":
        $color = "#eee";
        break;
    case "3":
        $color = "#bbb";
        break;
    default:
        $color = "#fff";
}
```

and then can use `$color` variable to apply color on `TD` as below:

```
echo "<tr> 
       <td>".$result['exportid']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['deb_nmr']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['cost_name']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['numb_pal']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['tot_weight']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['pb_s']."</td> 
       <td>".$result['date']."</td> 
       <td bgcolor='".$color."' >".$result['statusid']."</td>
 </tr>";
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Rohit sir while adding switch statement it is not working

Comment: Is there any possibility to write if else condition for the td

Comment: what is the value in your statusid field?